# Canceling a color specification

Tags: graphics3d, color

I can get the default colors for one figure (Cuboid), and then color another figure (Sphere), as here:

```
Graphics3D[
 {Cuboid[],
  Red, Sphere[]}
 ]
```

[image]

However, if I create the figures in the reverse order (Cuboid first, Sphere second), I need to "cancel" the color specification (from the sphere) so that the Cuboid is in its default colors.  I've tried FaceForm[Automatic] and variations, but these do not work.

Of course I could always specify the order of rendering to place the colors *last*, or explicitly place colored objects in Lists, but that is a bit tedious for many of my figures.

Comment: Why don't you group the colour with the object? `{Cuboid[], {Red, Sphere[]}}`.

Comment: @Szabolcs:  Yes, I can do that (+1), but I generate some figures algorithmically, and it gets a bit complicated to do this (though not impossible).  Is there really no way to "cancel" a previous color specification?  By analogy, one can "cancel" a `Dashing` specification with `Dashing[None]`.

Comment: I believe the default is `White`.

Comment: @Szabolcs:  Ah yes... helpful.  I didn't think the default was `White` given the rendered colors.  But this appears to work.  (You can post this as a quick solution and I'll accept it.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Graphics directives only persist inside the [`List`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/List) that they are defined in`. So, use extra lists to control where the directives are active:

```
Graphics3D[{{Red, Sphere[]}, Cuboid[]}]
```

[image]

Another possibility is to use [`Style`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Style) wrappers:

```
Graphics3D[{Style[Sphere[], Red], Cuboid[]}]
```

> same picture

Another possibility that is similar to your [`Dashing`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dashing) example is to use a rule :

```
Graphics3D[{Red, Sphere[], FrontFaceColor->White, Cuboid[]}]
```

> same picture

In this case you can also just change the color back to white without a rule, e.g., `Graphics3D[{Red, Sphere[], White, Cuboid[]}]`, but knowing about the rule possibility is useful.

You can examine what other rule possibilities there are by evaluating:

```
CurrentValue[{StyleDefinitions, "Graphics3D"}]
```

> {CellMargins -> {{4, Inherited}, {Inherited, Inherited}}, 
>    CellGroupingRules -> "GraphicsGrouping", StripStyleOnPaste -> False, 
>    PageBreakWithin -> False, GeneratedCell -> True, 
>    CellAutoOverwrite -> True, ShowCellLabel -> False, 
>    DefaultFormatType -> DefaultOutputFormatType, 
>    ContextMenu -> {MenuItem["Cu&t Graphics Selection", "Cut"], 
>      MenuItem["&Copy Graphics Selection", "Copy"], 
>      MenuItem["&Paste into Graphic", FrontEnd`Paste[After]], Delimiter, 
>      MenuItem["&Drawing Tools", 
>       FrontEndExecute[{FrontEnd`NotebookOpen[
>          FrontEnd`FindFileOnPath["DrawingTools.nb", 
>           "PrivatePathsSystemResources"]]}]], 
>      MenuItem["&Get Coordinates", 
>       FrontEndExecute[FrontEnd`Select2DTool["GetCoordinates"]]], 
>      Delimiter, MenuItem["G&roup", "Group"], 
>      MenuItem["&Ungroup", "Ungroup"], Delimiter, 
>      MenuItem["Move to &Front", "MoveToFront"], 
>      MenuItem["Move to &Back", "MoveToBack"], 
>      MenuItem["Move For&ward", "MoveForward"], 
>      MenuItem["Move Bac&kward", "MoveBackward"]}, 
>    "AutoStyleOptionsHighlightMisspelledWords" -> False, 
>    LanguageCategory -> "NaturalLanguage", FormatType -> StandardForm, 
>    ShowStringCharacters -> False, NumberMarks -> False, 
>    CounterIncrements -> "Graphics", 
>    ImageMargins -> {{43, Inherited}, {Inherited, 0}}, 
>    Arrowheads -> 0.04, Dashing -> None, CapForm -> "Round", 
>    JoinForm -> "Round", LineColor -> GrayLevel[0], LineOpacity -> 1, 
>    EdgeColor -> GrayLevel[0], EdgeOpacity -> 1, 
>    EdgeThickness -> Absolute[0.5], EdgeDashing -> None, 
>    EdgeCapForm -> "Round", EdgeJoinForm -> "Round", 
>    FrontFaceColor -> GrayLevel[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HDHnV.png), FrontFaceGlowColor -> GrayLevel[0], 
>    FrontFaceSpecularColor -> GrayLevel[0], 
>    FrontFaceSpecularExponent -> 1.5, BackFaceColor -> GrayLevel[1], 
>    BackFaceGlowColor -> GrayLevel[0], 
>    BackFaceSpecularColor -> GrayLevel[0], 
>    BackFaceSpecularExponent -> 1.5, FrontFaceOpacity -> 1, 
>    BackFaceOpacity -> 1, GraphicsColor -> GrayLevel[0], 
>    PointSize -> Absolute[3], Thickness -> Absolute[0.5], Opacity -> 1, 
>    DrawEdges -> True, DrawFrontFaces -> True, DrawBackFaces -> True, 
>    StyleMenuListing -> None, FontFamily -> "Arial", FontSize -> 10, 
>    FontWeight -> "Plain", FontColor -> GrayLevel[0], FontOpacity -> 1}

Comment: @CarlWolf:  Yes, I can do that (+1), but I generate some figures algorithmically, and it gets a bit complicated to do this (though not impossible).  Is there really no way to "cancel" a previous color specification?  By analogy, one can "cancel" a `Dashing` specification with `Dashing[None]`.  I believe one can "cancel" a previous `EdgeForm` with `EdgeForm[Automatic]`.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork See update.