# How can I get back to Solid in a list of line specifications?

Tags: graphics

When I make a Graphics list of line or arrow types, I can sequentially specify, dashed, dotted, color, etc. But I can't get back to Solid. There seems to be no command for that. Is this an oversight by Mathematica or am I missing something. Colors don't differentiate that greatly on my monitor, for Mathematica, and it would be useful to get back to Solid without complications. That is, in something like

```
g = Graphics[{Thick, Red, ar1, Black, ar2, Purple, ar3, Dashed, Magenta, ar4, Black, ar5}, Frame -> True]
```

I'd like to put Solid in front of ar5.

Comment: "Dashing[0]" will do what you want.

Comment: It made the Dashing a lot smaller but still there. But at least it looks different, which is what I'm looking for since the color separation on my system sucks. Ah, I tried AbsoluteDashing[0] and it does look solid.

Comment: Apply the directives to only one element by enclosing them in braces:  `Graphics[{Thick, {Red, ar1}, {Black, ar2}, {Dashed, Magenta, ar4}, {Black, ar5}]`.

Comment: That also works. Now I have two solutions 

Comment: Use `Dashing[None]` to return to a solid line after `Dashed`, `Dotted`, `Dashing[...]`, etc.

Comment: or `Dashing->None`

Comment: See also: [How do you turn off the Dashed graphics directive?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/58992/27951), [Canceling a color specification](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/207125/27951).